The use of netty's connection pool
Background:.
When deploying an application and running it, it runs fine, but after leaving it for a period of time (1-2 weeks), it suddenly becomes an error(*).
The firewall in between the application and the connection pool is blocking communication if left unattended for more than 1 hour, and this behavior is the direct cause of the error when the connection pool is used for more than 1 hour.
(*)IBMMobileFramework.IBM.Maf.Core.MafException.MafSysException: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: nested exception is io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException

if max-idle-time is not set for netty connection pools, are they not permanently destroyed?

is it possible for existing connection pools to be destroyed at certain times (e.g. when the connection pool is used up)?

how many connection pools are defined by default in netty?


That this error can be avoided by granting the max-idle-timeout setting.
